# How to get string before char?

Tags: php, strstr

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."\n";
echo strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```

`strrchr` returns the same adress as it was before, but i need all until last **/**.

Update:
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = /users/dev/index.php`
i need `/users/dev/`

Comment: @glavić i need only url path to index.php

Comment: Can you output what REQUEST_URI is, and what you need from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr()` and `strrpos()`:

```
$url = '/users/dev/index.php';
echo substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use regex if you have different .php file names

$s = '/users/dev/index.php';

```
preg_match('~^(.*?)([^/]+\.php)~', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```

#### Use substr() if you only have index.php

```
$m = substr($s, 0, strpos($s, 'index.php'));
print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
print_r(pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
```

Comment: Same as `dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.